# Cannot see some documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I use Go and https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver package.

Firstly, I had a problem with pinging DB. I got "context deadline exceeded" every time using
`err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())`.

The solution was adding **connect=direct** at the end of the URI:
mongodb://mongo_address.com:27017/?**connect=direct**.

And now when my Go app can connect to the database some documents are invisible.
I can see those documents using the mongod console, but my Go app can't.

I suppose that it is related to replicas but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the replica set option

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl
```

check the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-formats)

another example [here](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#ex-Connect--ReplicaSet)

```
clientOpts :=options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018/?replicaSet=replset")
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
_ = client
```